# Is a general-purpose function/object doubling decorator feasible in Python?

Tags: python, object, copy, decorator

**Background:**
Let's say that we have a function that opens a frequently-used database connection, something essentially like the following but with additional bells and whistles:

```
import getpass

import MySQLdb

def myspecialconnect(user='foo', host='bar', port=80085):
    password = getpass.getpassword('Enter your password: ')
    return MySQLdb.connect(user, password, host, port)
```

And maybe sometimes, we want to open two connections, along the lines of:

```
read_connection = myspecialconnect()
write_connection = myspecialconnect()
```

What a pain - I have to enter my password twice, when all I want is the same thing again. Of course, there are many ways to modify this one example to avoid that - *for example*, an argument could be added like `myspecialconnect(multi=True)` to return two connections instead of one, or `myspecialconnect(copies=9)` if you want to get crazy, with the corresponding code to make that happen inside this one function. However, this special case prompted me to wonder about a more general application.

**Question**: What if I wanted to be able to get this functionality (return multiple copies of whatever we want) from any arbitrary function? Hmm - this could be tricky.

First, just to confirm that it doesn't work, I tried this:

```
def doubled(function):
    def Wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return (function(*args, **kwargs),function(*args, **kwargs))
    return Wrapper
```

That's okay for a function that requires no user input; otherwise, you still have to sit there and input the exact same thing twice in a row. That's easy enough to fix, but by now you might be able to see where this is going:

```
def doubled(function):
    def Wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = function(*args, **kwargs)
        return (result, result)
    return Wrapper
```

This version takes user input only once, but it returns the same reference twice, making it nothing more than a needlessly convoluted way to do `foo = bar = object()`. "Aha!" says I, "maybe I should take a look at the `copy` module." Which is what I did, only I don't quite know how it works yet...

```
>>> import copy
>>> a = (i for i in [1,2])
>>> a
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x03FB0878>
>>> copy.copy(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\copy.py", line 96, in copy
    return _reconstruct(x, rv, 0)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\copy.py", line 329, in _reconstruct
    y = callable(*args)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\copy_reg.py", line 93, in __newobj__
    return cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: object.__new__(generator) is not safe, use generator.__new__()
>>> copy.deepcopy(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\copy.py", line 329, in _reconstruct
    y = callable(*args)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5\lib\copy_reg.py", line 93, in __newobj__
    return cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: object.__new__(generator) is not safe, use generator.__new__()
```

Of course by now I've spent about as much time as I can possibly justify (or more) on this little side problem, which means I'm incredibly curious. Can this be done in a way that returns copies of arbitrary instances, without turning into a monster that is forced to explicitly handle dozens of cases, each in their own special way?

Comment: Do you want an actual copy or do you want an entire new instance?

Comment: The ideal `@doubled` decorator would function such that `a, b = doubled(getSomething)()` is equivalent to `a = getSomething()` and `b = getSomething()` separately. Which means new instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no general way to do what you want. It'd be simple if you just wanted to replay the first function call - your first try would've worked. Unfortunately, the requirement to replay user input complicates things.

First, you don't want a copy. How would you copy a database connection? There's state over on the other side of a network connection that you'd have to duplicate, and you'd have to pick new ports, and it wouldn't end up really being a copy in the sense of having the same state and properties. You want to open up a new connection with the same parameters as the old one.

Second, there's no way for the decorator to know which inputs to replay. Calling a function twice with the same arguments is easy. Calling a function twice, replaying the user's input from the first call into the second call, is messy but possible. However, if the decorator tried to replay absolutely all input from the first call into the second call, it would end up replaying the database's TCP responses, too. Instead of talking to the database and setting up a connection, the second call would talk to the decorator and return a connection object that doesn't work.

Instead of trying to double `myspecialconnect`, make a function that doesn't need to read user input and double that. Read the password once, then pass that into a doubled function.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Here's a general solution if I understood your question properly as well as an example to go along.

```
generator = None

def getObject(askOnce = None, createFunction = None, *args):
    global generator
    if generator is None:
        askOnceValue = askOnce()
        generator = getGenerator(askOnceValue, createFunction, *args)
    return generator.next()

def getGenerator(askOnceValue, createFunction, *args):
    while(True):
        yield createFunction(askOnceValue, *args)

def myInputFunction():
    return "Some dynamic value"

def myCreateFunction(myInput, arg1, arg2):
    return list([myInput, arg1, arg2])

myObj1 = getObject(myInputFunction, myCreateFunction, "hello", 1234)

print(myObj1)

myObj2 = getObject()

print(myObj2)
```

This could be made much nicer by creating a class CopyableObject (terrible name..) and then extending it.

Comment: Yes and now that I have fixed my mistakes you will not have to.

Comment: This is interesting, but doesn't answer the question I asked. I'll add some emphasis to the OP to clarify that question.